# PostgreSQL replicate changes to selected tables to another, disconnected instance

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have two PostgreSQL instances, one in different countries.
There are no network connections between them.
But I can open VPN, use scp, etc to copy files.

Only selected tables need to be replicated. Intermittent replication is fine.

I read about physical replication, logical replication.
These do not seem to be what I need.

foreign tables, seems to require a network connection as well.

Triggers seem too complicated.

I think pg_dump tables of interest,
then drop tables and pg_restore should work.

Is there a better method?
Thanks for any pointers!

Similar question for MySQL

Comment: Better in terms of what? Is there something you cannot achieve with your current approach?

Comment: Thanks for the comment!
pg_dump, drop table, pg_restore seems crude to me. I was hoping there may be a more elegant and less destructive method.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you are using very vague terms, such as crude and elegant. Pls be specific as to what requirement this method does not satisfy because then we can either suggest you an alternative way of using pg_dump / pg_restore, or we can suggest a completely different solution.